# Server-client connection; what I'm missing?

Tags: c#, java, client

I got a working server in C# and a working client in Java (Android). It's totally working, but the connection itself is only one-wayed. Only the client can send data to the server. I tried to make the connection two-sided, but the code not working by an unknown reason.

Where I do it wrong?

**C#- server**

```
public void SendBack(string message, NetworkStream stream)
{
  if (stream.CanWrite)
  {
    byte[] candy = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message + ";");

    stream.Write(candy, 0, candy.Length);
    stream.Flush();

    Console.WriteLine("[SENT] " + message);
  }
  else { Console.WriteLine("ERROR! CANNOT WRITE ON NETWORKSTREAM!"); }
}
```

**Java- client**

```
//Creating the stream in the constructor
bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gSocket.getInputStream()));

new Thread (new Runnable(){
  public void run() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Started listerner...");
    ListenServer();
  }
}).start();

//The function itself
private void ListenServer(){
  try
  {
    String inputLine = "";
    while (true){
      inputLine = bReader.readLine();
      if (inputLine != null) Log.d(TAG, "Got: " + inputLine);
    }
  }
  catch (IOException e){ Log.d(TAG, "Could not listen to sever!"); }
}
```

Edit: forget to mention whats the actual problem... I start the server, behaves like usual, client can send data, which the server can interpret the message. Hoverwer, if the server sends something, the client do nothing. I mean, it does not execute the

```
Log.d(TAG, "Got: " + inputLine);
```

code.

Comment: Does the code actually reach the point where you create the `new Thread` and start it? If it does, then there is something REALLY strange happening here.

Comment: It could be that the server is not sending the line-feed and/or carriage-return. [BufferedReader.readLine()(link)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) expects it.

Comment: The new thread (and the loop) runs great, but INSIDE the loop the code not runs as I tought.

I'm going to check what happens if I manually add a cr. Thank you.

Comment: You can construct a `StreamWriter` with the incoming `stream`, and use one of the `WriteLine` methods.

Comment: @srkavin I'm now yelling a BIG THANK YOU to you. The carriage return was the problem. I only needed to add a "\n" to the sent string. Please, take all my respect, you saved my night!

Comment: @LugaidVandroiy I'm glad it helped. Shall I go ahead, post my comment as an answer? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that the server is not sending the line-feed and/or carriage-return. `BufferedReader.readLine()`[(link)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) expects it. You can construct a StreamWriter with the incoming stream, and use one of the `WriteLine` methods.